# MonoGame.Extended.Tiled: Get layers for Vector2 location without iterating over all tiles? Extended

Tags: c#, monogame

I am trying to get the layers (or better, a special object layer) which contains a Vector2 location from a TiledMap, I know I could iterate over those, but I do not want to. How would I do that?

Thanks!

PS: I already asked at the MonoGame.Extended forums, but I may not get an answer there. That's why I'm asking here, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `GetLayer` method on the `TiledMap`?

Depending on your use case, you can get the object layer specifically by using either use the generic method:

```
var objectLayer = map.GetLayer<TiledMapObjectLayer>("layerName");
```

Or you can cast it you the object layer yourself:

```
var objectLayer = map.GetLayer("layerName") as TiledMapObjectLayer;
```

In either case it will return `null` if the layer doesn't exist or is of the wrong type.